# Removing the borders from algorithm listings

Tags: captions, algorithms, rules

I am relatively new to LaTeX. If I use standard `algorithm` and `algorithmic` environment for my algorithm listings I'm getting the borders displayed around the table with the pseudocode. How to remove them? I also want to have the caption of the algorithm below the pseudocode - it is currently above. I believe the problem is extremely easy but googling didn't give me any hints for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the `algorithm` package, it is enough to use the `plain` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \STATE $sum\gets 0$
  \STATE $i\gets 1$
  \WHILE{$i\le n$}
  \STATE $sum\gets sum+i$
  \STATE $i\gets i+1$
  \ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Calculate $y = x^n$}
\label{alg:test}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is it! I knew it must be a fast hack :-)

Comment: @Jamie: It isn't a fast hack. It is reading the documentation.

Comment: Can this option `plain` be set locally for a specific algorithm, leaving other algorithms with borders?

Comment: For reference, the answer to hengxin's question is no. The package [documentation](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf) states this only as a global option. We can get a solution by wrapping our `algorithmic` environment in an unnamed figure. If we want any of the lines, we can use `\hrulefill` to add these.