# Removing the borders from algorithm listings

Tags: algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing the borders from algorithm listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19807/removing-the-borders-from-algorithm-listings)

I am relatively new to Latex. If I use standard `algorithm` and `algorithmic` for my algorithm listings I'm getting the borders displayed around the table with the pseudocode. How to remove them?
I als want to have the caption of the algorithm below the pseudocode - it is currently above.
I believe the problem is extremely easy but googling didn't give me any hints for that.

Comment: @Jamie: enclose your inline code with a pair of ` signs so you can save more keystrokes than what you did (enclosing the code with `<code>`). :-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
\STATE $y \leftarrow 1$
...
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Calculate $y = x^n$}
\label{alg1}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]